# Android display non-modal popup notification message

Tags: android, popup

I need to display Android's non-modal notification message (the one that appears at middle-to-bottom of the screen with rounded corners, semi-transparent black background and simple white text), but I don't know where to start because I don't know the name of it.

I've seen many examples of regular status bar notifications and modal alert dialogs, I know how to create them. How can I create what I've described above?

Comment: It's not a built-in element. You can see in different apps in Lollipop because it's the default "share" element. You can create one yourself or you can find a library that does it. But there's nothing out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Budius oh, as many apps had it I thought it's something native. I'll be making my own then :)